# 2d running animation not playing

Tags: animation, godot, gdscript

in godot using gdscript when i run this code the runing animation is not playing but the other animation is playing fine. eventhogh i have went over the code a few times i still dont know why

this is the code:
`

```
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    apply_gravity()
    var input = Vector2.ZERO
    input.x = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    
    if input.x == 0:
        apply_friction()
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "idle"
    else:
        apply_acceleration(input.x)
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "run"
        if input.x > 0:
            $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true
        elif input.x < 0:
            $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = false
    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
            velocity.y = JUMP_FORCE
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.animation = "jump"
        if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and velocity.y < JUMP_RELEASE_FORCE:
            velocity.y = JUMP_RELEASE_FORCE


    if velocity.y > 0:
        velocity.y += ADDITIONAL_FALL_GRAVITY

    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

func apply_gravity():
    velocity.y += GRAVITY
    
func apply_friction():
    velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x, 0, FRICiON)
    
func apply_acceleration(amount):
    velocity.x = move_toward(velocity.x , MAX_SPEED * amount, ACCEL)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Play` method instead of (or in addition to) setting the `animation` property.